# PHP - Error traversing multidimensional associative array from Youtube API

Tags: php, arrays, youtube-api, syntax-error

I've been trying for a while to find out why I get an error when trying to traverse this array that the Youtube API generates (tree obtained by print_r):

```
Array
(
    [nextPageToken] => CAIQAA
    [items] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [snippet] => Array
                        (
                            [resourceId] => Array
                                (
                                    [videoId] => sGIm0-dQd8M
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [snippet] => Array
                        (
                            [resourceId] => Array
                                (
                                    [videoId] => VGd1ml4Hvas
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

In the first instance, I tried foreach but it generates an error:

```
$data_decode = json_decode($data, true); //here I get my array

foreach ($data_decode as $decode){
    foreach ($decode as $code){
        echo $code['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId'];
    }
}

Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

I think the problem is for the "nextPageToken" node, which I need to have.
What is the correct way to traverse this array?

Comment: a few levels too shallow.  `$code` is an array that contains `nextPageToken` and `items` as keys.  So `snippet` is in `array[items][0]['snippet']`

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($data_decode['items'] as $item){
   echo $element['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId'];
}
```

Just a tip, it's much easier on me if you use `var_export` instead of `print_r` var_export will print an array that is syntactically correct for PHP, print_r prints an array in a human readable format.

Therefor I have to take your example data and replace all the `[key]` with `"key"` quote the values and add in commas before I can use it in code to test with.

I can do it, but it's tedious.